# Is there a more up to date RSS feed API for Python than Feedparser?

Tags: python, rss, rdf, feedparser

Seems it hasn't been updated in a while, and lacks support for things like sy:updateFrequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

feedparser trunk in it's SVN repository was last updated a few days ago: [feedparser.py](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/source/browse/trunk/feedparser/feedparser.py)
You can try it to see if it fits your needs, or even look in it's source to see if it can be extended to support what you need...

I also found [this one](http://gist.github.com/221419) but I have never used it...

hope it helps.